# Spark Job - Scala Objects are read in FIFO order, How to make it parallel?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a Scala - Spark Program is shown below

Here the Scala Objects Season, product, Vendor.....Groups are run in serial order, FIFO, is there a way to make it parallel? Submit all jobs at once?

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object Main extends App {
  var appName: String = "DataExtract"
  var master: String = "local[*]"

  val sparkConf: SparkConf = new SparkConf()
    .setAppName(appName)
    .setMaster(master)

  val spark: SparkSession = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .config(sparkConf)
    .getOrCreate()

  Season.run(spark)
  Product.run(spark)
  Vendor.run(spark)
  User.run(spark)
  ..
  ..
  .
  Group.run(spark)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make *spark* jobs run asynchronously you would just need to wrap them in `Future`:

```
import scala.concurrent.{Await, Future}
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits._
import scala.concurrent.duration._


val jobs = Future.sequence(
    List(
      Future(Season.run(spark)),
      Future(Product.run(spark)),
      Future(Vendor.run(spark)),
      Future(User.run(spark))
    )
)

Await.result(jobs, 1 hour); //we need to block main thread 
                            //to allow jobs in other threads to finish
                            //You can replace finite duration with Duration.Inf
```

Additionally you'd have to set *spark* job scheduler to *FAIR*:

```
sparkConf.set("spark.scheduler.mode", "FAIR")
```

Comment: Great! I could not find this option in help docs, thanks Atlasik

Comment: @Sandeep540 Please check this [article](http://www.russellspitzer.com/2017/02/27/Concurrency-In-Spark/) for more details.

Comment: I think you should also set `spark.scheduler.mode` to `"FAIR"`, otherwise your jobs, albeit submitted together, may execute sequentially (under resource constraint), since the default is `"FIFO"`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application.

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks for remark, I forgot about scheduler. I edited my anwser.